# JS integration test to detect if youtube video is playing

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, integration-testing, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to create an integration test in javascript to detect if a youtube video is playing. I'm using mocha and zombie (headless browser) to run the tests. Wondering if anyone has any recommendations of how to test this from functional/integration standpoint in which the user's "play" and "pause" mouse clicks can be simulated?

I've seen some approaches involving the swfObject and ExternalInterface in JS but that doesn't seem appropriate for a high-level integration test where the end user's behavior is mimicked.

Thanks.

Comment: The youtube javascript API has something that you're looking for. They have different events you can use to detect when a video is changed played or paused. https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events You could also use these APIs the control the video playback https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls

Comment: Yes, I'm using those methods in my unit tests to test individual methods for playing, pausing, etc. I'm actually trying a higher-level approach to simulate a user clicking on the video and testing if it starts playing. These would be functional tests (browser level) rather than individual unit tests (code level).